# How do I read data from a file from each line and store it into a structure array

Tags: c

Below is my code, I have been working on this part for some structure am create a C socket server that can process data for clients, but I got a problem in file handling. I wanted to pick data from a file and store it into a structure at specific portions and then I erase the file according to data I have picked.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "struct.h"

struct student {
    char command[10];
    char value[50];
    char user[50];
};

int main() {
    int size, i;
    struct student s1[256];
    FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "r");

    if (file == NULL) {

        printf("Error in reading student data");
        return 1;
    }
    size = 0;

    while(fscanf(file,"%s,%s,%s",
                 s1[size].command,
                 s1[size].value,
                 s1[size].user) != EOF) {

        printf("%s%s%s\n",s1[size].command,s1[size].value,s1[size].user);
        printf("%s\n",s1[size].command);
        size++;
    }

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to pick data from my file which contains the below information and I store it in specific portions of my structure array

```
a,w,a
r,e,1
```

i.e. if I store

```
a in s1[0].command
w in s1[0].value
a in s1[0].user
```

and

```
r in s1[1].command
e in s1[1].value
1 in s1[1].user
```

But when I try running my code it prints

```
a, w, a in s1[0].command
```

and

```
r, e, 1 in s1[1].command
```

so I am kindly requesting for help because I have tried googling but I couldn't get a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"%s"` format reads ***space-separated*** "words".

If there isn't a space separating the "words" you have to use some other way to parse the input. For example by [reading the whole line](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and then use something like [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) to "tokenize" the string.

*Or* make sure that the input format is space-separated.

Comment: and don't forget the buffer overflow with `%s` (or `%[`) when used without a field width ...

Comment: @ Felix Palmen can u help me and re-write  the full code because am tired of stressing

Comment: Thank you so much for your time lemmi try and i see if i can solve it according to your explanation..@ Felix Palmen